# Как открыть pdf файл на Android 6

Tags: android, pdf

В манифесте указано разрешение

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

В коде

```
file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/ccAlTT_D__.pdf");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intentOpenFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intentOpenFile.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
intentOpenFile.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intentOpenFile);
```

Путь  к файлу правильный. Этот код работает на версиях ниже 6, а в шестой на мгновение открывает pdf файл и тут же его сворачивает, при этом оставляя в логах -

```
12-23 14:06:53.248 18679-16520/? E/DisplayData: openFd: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied
12-23 14:06:53.248 18679-16520/? E/PdfLoader: Can't load file (doesn't open)  Display Data [PDF : ccAlTT_D__.pdf] +UriOpenable
12-23 14:06:53.381 881-896/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Если есть идеи по этому поводу, прошу высказаться.

Comment: А если добавить `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб нет. не работает

Comment: Скорей всего дело в пути, не рекомендуется делать в таком хардкорном виде. попробуйте сделать типа  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/ccAlTT_D__.pdf"

Comment: `В Android 6` разрешения нужно запрашивать. Чтобы не запрашивать разрешения, поставьте `Target SDK 22`, или ниже

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, я так написал для примера. С `getExternalStorageDirectory() ` не работает, давно проверял

Answer (score 3):

В логах же написано

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied

Значит, дело либо в том, что программа для чтения pdf не поддерживает android 6, либо в том, что для android 6 нужно использовать другой способ.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что в шестой версии Android при установке приложения пользователь не дает согласие на использование программой тех или иных прав доступа (разработчики посчитали что это часто отпугивало пользователя от установки приложений). Вместо этого теперь нужно вручную при запуске программы (или при начале определённого действия) запрашивать доступ в пользователя. Например вот так: (или заменить `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` на `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` для большей универсальности)

```
// проверка есть ли права доступа к файловой системе
  if (getContext().checkSelfPermission(
     Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
     PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

     // показать сообщение о необходимости получить права
     if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder =
           new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setMessage(R.string.permission_explanation);

        // кнопка OK диалога с запросом доступа
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 // запрос на доступ
                 requestPermissions(new String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
              }
           }
        );
        builder.create().show();
     }
     else {
        // запрос на доступ
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
     }
  }
  else { // если у нас уже есть доступ, делаем то что нам нужно
     file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/ccAlTT_D__.pdf");
     Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
     Intent intentOpenFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     intentOpenFile.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
     intentOpenFile.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     startActivity(intentOpenFile);
  }
```